# Is there a way to select/ delete all/ multiple images in an album on the ipad, either manually or programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, photo

Is there a way to select all/multiple images in an album on the ipad, either manually or programmatically?

Secondly, Is there a way to delete all/ multiple images from an album on the ipad?  Manually or programmatically

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to select all/multiple images in an album on the ipad, either manually or programmatically?

Yes, you can use the [AssetsLibrary framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) to find all the photos in the library.

> Secondly, Is there a way to delete all/ multiple images from an album on the ipad? Manually or programmatically

No the AssetsLibrary framework does not allow deleting assets (photos and videos) from an album.